# how to test dreamweaver site on iphone

Tags: iphone, dreamweaver

I know this seems kind of silly. I have an iphone here, and I need to test the site I'm working on in dreamweaver. Do I save it a certain way and email it to myself, and then open it in the iphone? Whats the best way to do this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Exposing/Testing your site on an iPhone is no different than making the site available to any client. You have to publish the site in one way or another.

I'd begin by getting the free iPhone emulator included in Webmatrix2, link here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SimulatingAnIPhoneOrIPadBrowserForASPNETMobileWebDevelopmentWithWebMatrix2OrVisualStudio2012.aspx

To actually show the page on your iphone you have to expose your website using a webserver. Webmatrix can help you with that, or just upload your site to any hosting provider.

Microsoft Azure is a hosting platform great to use when trying stuff and i highly recommend it!

How to use Webmatrix to publish a site: http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/how-to-publish-a-web-application-using-webmatrix

Answer (score 0):

There is one useful thing - [Edge Inspect](http://html.adobe.com/edge/inspect/). Using this plugin you can simply connect any device to the computer and do preview (like a preview in browser). The page will be automaticly uploaded to the server (you need a testing server to use Edge Inspect) and shown on the device.